# Performance report (.vspx) not opening(showing corrupt) in Visual studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, profiling, cpu

I am doing profiling for the code developed in MFC VC++ in Visual studio 2013. After stopping profiling, the report gets generated. But when i try to launch the performance report. It shows the following error:-

**Invalid report: The data in the file is corrupt or has invalid format**

I tried searching on the net. but it haven't helped much. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I am building the project on 64 bit windows 10 enviornment

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Reinstall the Visual Studio 2015 (2013 may be the same) works for me.

Not work: Reset or Change settings; Modify or Repair.